# Followup script to 'npm run build'

Tags: node.js, npm, scripting

After building my create-react-app `npm run build`? I need to run another script to make further changes to the final build. Is there any way to simply chain to after `react-scripts build` in package.json? I've tried chaining it with ';' but it just fails then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try "&&" to join the commands.
For example:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "dev": "cd server && npm run start"
 }
```